# puppet client reporting to wrong host in Foreman

Tags: report, puppet, hostname, theforeman

This is my first post!

I have 100's of nodes managed by puppet/foreman. Everything is fine.
I did something I already did without problem in the past:
Change the hostname of a server.

This time I changed 2 hostnames:

Initially I had 'gate02' and 'gate03'.

I moved gate02 to 'gate02old' (with dummy IP, and switched the server OFF)

then I moved gate03 to gate02 ...

Now (the new) gate02 reports are updating the host called gate02old in foreman.

I did clean the certs in the puppetserver. I rm the ssl dir in the (new) gate02 and run puppet agent. I did not fing any reference to 'gate' in /var/lib/puppet. I changed the certname in puppet.conf and in hostname, and in sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-xxxx.

The puppet agent run smoothly, and sends it to the puppetserver. But it updates the wrong host!

Anyone would have a clue on how to fix this ?

Thanks!

Foreman 2.0.3
Puppet 6

Comment: For completness, 'hostname' and 'hostanme -f' are returning  both gate02.right-domain.com

Comment: Puppet nodes identify themselves to their server via certname, not (directly) via hostname.  The server classifies them and reports on them via certname.  If reports for a given node are being logged for name xyz, then that's because the node is presenting a cert identifying it as xyz, and the server is successfully verifying that cert.

Answer (score 1):

I do not accept that the sequence of events described led to the behavior described.  If reports for the former `gate03`, now named `gate02`, are being logged on the server for name `gate02old`, then that is because that machine is presenting a cert to the server that identifies it as `gate02old` (and the server is accepting that cert).  The sequence of events presented does not explain how that might be, but my first guess would be that it is actually (new) `gate02old` that is running and requesting catalogs from the server, not (new) `gate02`.

Fix it by

0. Ensuring that the machine you want running is in fact the one that *is* running, and that its hostname is in fact what you intend for it to be.
1. Shutting down the agent on (new) `gate02`.  If it is running in daemon mode then shut down the daemon and disable it.  If it is being scheduled by an external scheduler then stop and disable it there.  Consider also using `puppet agent --disable`.
2. Deactivating the node on the server and cleaning out its data, including certs:

   ```
   puppet node deactivate gate02
   puppet node deactivate gate02old
   puppet node deactivate gate03
   ```

   You may want to wait a bit at this point, then ...

   ```
   puppet node clean gate02
   puppet node clean gate02old
   puppet node clean gate03
   ```
3. Cleaning out the nodes' certs.  For safety, I would do this on *both* nodes.  Removing `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl` (on the nodes, not the server!) should work for that, or you could remove the puppet-agent package altogether, remove any files left behind, and then reinstall.
4. Updating the puppet configuration on the new `gate02` as appropriate.
5. Re-enabling the agent on `gate02`, and starting it or running it in `--test` mode.
6. Signing the new CSR (unless you have autosigning enabled), which should have been issued for `gate02` or whatever certname is explicitly specified in in that node's puppet configuration.

Comment: @SoFe, it seems highly likely that the situation is different from what you have presented and what you think it is.  I advise you to go back and check your assumptions, especially about what machines are actually running and making catalog requests, what certnames they are actually presenting, and where the reports are being logged.

Comment: Hello John, First, thanks for getting into my issue. I did the steps you gave, but to make it short, it did not work. I though I could attach a file with all details but I didn't figure out how. I will put it in 'answer'.

Comment: @SoFe do not post an answer that does not answer the question.  If you have additional details to present, then edit them into the question.  Do also be aware that we generally frown upon making substantive modifications to the question after it has been answered, but I promise not to object in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, though it was not the right one.
I did get to the right point by changing again the hostname of the old gateold02 to a another existing-for-testing one, starting the server and get it back in Foreman. Once that done, removing (again!) the certs of the new gate02 put it right, and its reports now updates the right entry in Foreman.

I still beleive there is something (a db ?) that was not updated right so foreman was sure that the host called 'gate02' was in the GUI 'gateold02'.

I am very sorry if you don't beleive me.

Not to say rather disappointed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had the same issue after renaming a node in the UI (Foreman Version 3.4.1) and adding a new node with the same hostname as the initial one from the renamed host.

cleaning and reissuing certs of both nodes did not help, what did help was

- delete the renamed host from foreman
- add it back with the new name (without build)
- clean certificates (`rm -rf  /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/`) on the respective node and issue new certificates with the new hostname (the hostname of the node was already adjusted in the initial attempt to rename the node)

after that all reports were associated with the correct nodes.